# Disable screensaver when connected via Screen Sharing?

Tags: screen-sharing, screensaver

I have my mac set to show a screensaver, but every now and then when I'm working away from home I'll connect to it using Screen Sharing from and leave it connected. If the screensaver starts running it can cause issues since it's suddenly forcing Screen Sharing to transmit a lot of motion over a possibly slow internet connection, making it difficult to interact with my system until the screensaver stops.

Is there any way to get the screensaver to be disabled when Screen Sharing is connected, but enabled the rest of the time?

Comment: How about disabling screensaver altogether? Or using something static as screensaver? The whole point of using a screensaver was to save displays from [burn in effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in) which is no longer applicable to modern devices.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Yes that's true, but I like screensavers and just want to have it enabled so that every now and then my screen displays something pretty and interesting looking.